# Java libraries to read/write C64 T64, D64 image files?

Tags: java, c64

I would like to read/write T64 and D64 from a Java program. Are there any libraries available to do that?

**EDIT**

I have looked at several C64 emulators that emulate the 1541, but the problem is they don't really offer a public API, but rather have the T64/D64 reading/writing code mixed up with other stuff.

Comment: [`AppleCommander`](http://applecommander.sourceforge.net/) does this for several Apple II disk formats. Have you looked at any C64 emulators?

Comment: Vote to reopen. I know of such a library and would like to answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Besides manually parsing any suggestions ?

There are a couple of Java-based C64 emulator projects.  Try reusing the code that they use to read the files.

Comment: I did, but there is no public API, most have the parsing code embedded within other emulation stuff.

Comment: @mP - I'm suggesting that you **extract** the parsing code.  The chances of a simpler solution seem pretty small at this point.